# Native iOS Classes are not recognized in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode isn't doing the auto suggest or recognizing any of native iOS Classes (NS family seems to be working but not UI family like UIImage).

I tried clearing the derived data from Xcode, did deep clean and re-started but still the same problem.

Anybody know why?

Comment: Try importing UIKit Framework.

Comment: in newer xcode you have to import `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` if you are using UI Family. in older xcode you dont need it.

Answer (score 0):

Trying deleting the following folders manually

- ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
- ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
- Restart Xcode

Answer (score 0):

This problem arise mainly due to two reason

- Firstly, if you are not included UIKit framework in your project and class.
- Secondly, by mistake you delete this framework.

For first problem, just include UIKit Framework in your **linked Frameworks and libraries** and import UIKit in the class where you want to use.

For second problem, you have to reinstall xcode again.